# Fastest data structure for a large index in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I need to create a large index for ~3-4 millions of tuples in the form of "x,y->7".
What would be the best data structure (in terms of speed) in groovy (or any of its external modules that can be imported) to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really bothered by performance, then use Java, and call this Java from Groovy.

3-4 Million is not that many objects though...

```
@groovy.transform.Canonical
class Tuple {
  def x, y
}

Map<Tuple,Integer> values = [:]

values[ new Tuple( 3, 5 ) ] = 7
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, I am trying it now but for some reason getting a "No such property" error when I am trying to call the values map inside a function (tried adding a @Field, didn't work). Any idea as to why?

Comment: @user any chance you could add the troublesome code to your question? Without seeing it, I don't know what you're trying to do, or what error you're getting